# Does MongoEngine have an "AutoField()" like Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, mongoengine

I just switched from SQL to MongoDB. When I was changing all my model fields from Django fields to MongoEngine fields, I realized there was no `AutoField()`. Does anyone know a substitute for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ObjectIdField` of mongodb like this:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from mongoengine import Document, ObjectIdField

class ModelName(Document):
    id = ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, default=ObjectId)
```

and create your object in the model like this:

```
obj_doc = ModelName.objects.create(field1='value1', field2='value2')
```

then if want to check id of your object:

```
print(obj_doc.id)
```

here `id` of `obj_doc` will be created automatically.